# Is there a better way than using ArrayList so I don't get an IndexOutOfBounds exception?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<String> libraries = new ArrayList<String>(2);
ArrayList<String> styles = new ArrayList<String>(2);
```

I have 3 CheckBox components. The three CheckBoxes are supposed to add or remove strings to the ArrayList's however when **jqMobileChk** is checked an IndexOutOfBoundsException occurs.

The three CheckBoxes:

```
jqChk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(jqChk.isChecked()){
            libraries.add(0,"<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js\"></script>\n");
        }else if(!jqChk.isChecked()){
            libraries.remove(0);
        }
    }
});

jqMobileChk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(jqMobileChk.isChecked()){
            libraries.add(1,"<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js\"></script>\n");
        }else if(!jqMobileChk.isChecked()){
            libraries.remove(1);
        }
    }
});

jqMobCSS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(jqMobCSS.isChecked()){
            styles.add(0,"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css\" />\n");
        }else if(!jqMobCSS.isChecked()){
            styles.remove(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `new ArrayList(2)` does *not* create an ArrayList with 2 elements. It is initially empty - that is the "internal" capacity. Likewise, `add/remove` *changes the size* of the ArrayList. ArrayList != array.

Comment: Not really sure why this question was deemed unlikely to help future visitors. I found the answers very helpful and would likely help others in regards to the pitfalls of the ArrayList. Learning about the Map object type was also important. +1 for taking the time to explain things everyone.

Comment: Debugging. It's very important in programming. IndexOutOfBounds, NullReferenceException, etc .. these are caused by very particular conditions. Attach a debugger and have a look about. *It is the developer's job to isolate the conditions in which these occur in order to troubleshoot a problem.* Now, look at the title - will that *really* help anyone? No. Now, if the problem had *been isolated* in *minimal test case*, then perhaps. As it is now .. no.

Comment: I did use the debugger to pinpoint what was causing the  IndexOutOfBounds but didn't know how to fix it. I wouldn't have learned about Map had I not asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues:

- Don't use concrete types as a type signature; use the interface instead so that you can switch implementations later if you want to. Hence, use `List<String> libraries = ...` instead of `ArrayList<String> libraries = ...`.
- Creating a `List` with `2` as the argument to the constructor only creates a list with *room* for two elements. It doesn't mean that it contains two elements. When you do `libraries.remove(1)`, you're removing something that doesn't even exist.
- Instead of using a `List<String>` here, I think a `Map<Integer, String>` might be better:

Instead of doing `add(0, "...")`, you would do `libraries.put(0, "...");`. To remove, you can do `libraries.remove(0)`. You won't get an exceptions if the key doesn't exist. For example:

```
jqMobileChk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(jqMobileChk.isChecked()) {
            libraryMap.put(0, "<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js\"></script>\n");

        } else if(!jqMobileChk.isChecked()) {
            libraryMap.remove(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Also, instead of just `0` or `1`, it might be better to use the actual version number, so `1.3.0` instead of `0`. In this case, you would want to make your map into `Map<String, String>` and do the following:

```
jqMobileChk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(jqMobileChk.isChecked()) {

            libraryMap.put("1.3.0","<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js\"></script>\n");

        } else if(!jqMobileChk.isChecked()) {
            libraryMap.remove("1.3.0");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayList<String> libraries = new ArrayList<String>(2);
```

capacity 2, size 0

```
   libraries.remove(1);
```

ofc idnex out of bounds, since size is 0

Comment: I have a feeling this will work unpredictably after a series of selection changes ..

Comment: Yes, working with lists like this is unpredictable and error-prone. A `Map` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

From [`ArrayList.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

> **Throws:**
>       IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

There are no elements in the `ArrayList`, therefore the Exception.

You can use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead

```
Map<String, String> libraries = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and then

```
jqMobileChk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (jqMobileChk.isChecked()) {
            libraries.put("jqMobileChk","<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js\"></script>\n");
        } else if (!jqMobileChk.isChecked()) {
            libraries.remove("jqMobileChk");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Never knew about the Map. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can not add to index 1 if there is no index 0 in an ArrayList.

Use a "real" array or [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) instead - there you can do this.